# Xamarin.Android, How to call another method from another .cs file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Needed some help here, so I tried to run method from another .cs, I had the following code running in my mainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
startGame();
}

public void startGame()
{
 firstNum = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvFirstNum);
 secondNum = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvSecondNum);
 firstNum.Text = Convert.ToString(2);
 secondNum.Text = Convert.ToString(2);
}
```

Heres the thing, I tried to run the code from another CS file

```
    private void BtnRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainActivity mp = new MainActivity();
        mp.startGame();
    }
```

However I got the error of

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference

Does anyone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating your `MainActivity` class yourself, which does not load the accompanying Layout. That's because the lifecycle methods that Android uses aren't called, so your `OnCreate` method will never fire (which usually handles the layout). Therefore the `FindViewById` will return a null value.

A note: You shouldn't call views from another class (especially if it's another Activity) like you are trying to do here. If you still want to call this from another class, you can pass the Activity as a parameter, but I wouldn't recommend that approach.

I would recommend you to read the [Activity Lifecycle documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/).